# how to convert the data of Date.now() into String for the users to reed in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, express

I am trying to check the time received from data base and the present date and time so that the user will not be able to update the data send after some times

`var data = 1572613310373 ;`// **Date from Date.now()**;

```
`data = (Date.now()- data)`;//**The information is 78248**
```

**how to convert the data into  yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure if i understand your question, but if you want format from Date to String is easy.

```
data = (Date.now()- data).toString();
```

Comment: it does works but i want the data in mm dd yy fromat and it provides the date as "1734856"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**DayJs**](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) to format the date received from the server:

> Day.js is a minimalist JavaScript library that parses, validates, manipulates, and displays dates and times for modern browsers with a largely Moment.js-compatible API. If you use Moment.js, you already know how to use Day.js.

```js
const data = 1572613310373;
const formatedDate = dayjs(data).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
const output = Date.now() - data;
console.log(formatedDate);
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.8.16/dayjs.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function like this
You can also improve this function handling errors or invalid date

```js
var parseDate = function (date) {
  var d = new Date(date)

  // Year
  var year = d.getFullYear()

  // Month
  var month = (d.getMonth() + 1).toString()
  month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month

  // Day
  var day = d.getDay().toString()
  day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day

  // hours
  var hours = d.getHours().toString()
  hours = hours.length > 1 ? hours : '0' + hours

  // minutes
  var minutes = d.getMinutes().toString()
  minutes = minutes.length > 1 ? minutes : '0' + minutes

  // seconds
  var seconds = d.getSeconds().toString()
  seconds = seconds.length > 1 ? seconds : '0' + seconds

  return year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds
}

var date = parseDate(1572613310373)
console.log(date) // 2019-11-05 14:01:50
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = 1572613310373;
const formatedDate = dayjs(data).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
const output = Date.now() - data;
console.log(formatedDate);
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.8.16/dayjs.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```